# Show that $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is a measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$. Suppose that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a measurable set $E\subseteq [a,b]$ such that $m(E)<\epsilon$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\setminus E$. We want to prove that $f$ is a (Lebesgue) measurable function.

**Attempt**. For any $n\in \Bbb Z_{>0}$ there exists a measurable set $E_n\subseteq [a,b]$ zuch that $m(E_n)<1/n$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\setminus E_n$. We also define $f_n:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ by $f_n(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    f(x) & , x \in [a,b]\setminus E_n\\
    0 & , x \in E_n
  \end{array}
\right.
$. We claim that the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f$ a.e pointwise on $[a,b]$ i.e. $m(C)=0$ where $C=\{x\in [a,b] : \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\neq f(x)\}$. Note that if $x\in C$ then there exist $\epsilon>0$ and $N_x\in \Bbb N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon >0$ for all $n\geq N_x$. So, $x\in E_n$ for all $n\geq N_x$ and $f(x)\neq 0$, so $x\in\cap_{n\geq N_x}E_n$. So we get $$C\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in C}\bigcap_{n\geq N_x}E_n.$$
But, I couldn't go further from here. Could anyone check my work and give any suggestions? Thanks!

-**Update**-

$$C\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in C}\bigcap_{n\geq N_x}E_n \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n \implies 0\leq m(C)\leq m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\geq k}E_n\right)=\lim_{k\to \infty}m(\cap_{n\geq k}E_n)\leq\lim_{k\to\infty} m(E_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty} 1/k=0.$$
So $m(C)=0$. So, $f$ is measurable since $f_n$ is measurable for all $n\in \Bbb Z_{>0}$.

Comment: I suggest that you use uniform continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]\setminus E_n$. (you can assume that $E_n$ is closed btw)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I think it's an application of Lusin's not exactly Lusin's theorem

Comment: $N_x$ may not exist for $x \in C$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why do you think that $N_x$ may not exist for $x\in C$. I think $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ always exist for all $x\in [a,b]$. Thanks!

Comment: @ErginSuer I think it is because you don't have $E_{n+1}\subset E_n$ so the $f_n(x)$ can fluctuate around a point.

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that you wish to show that $f$ is **Lebesgue** measurable.

The trick is to define the approximations in a 'cumulative' way.

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $E^c$, then the function $f \cdot 1_{E^c}$ is measurable.

There is a sequence of $E_n$ such that $f$ is measurable on $E_n^c$ and $m E_n < {1 \over n}$. Let $E= \cap E_n$ and note that $m E = 0$.

Define $f_n = f \cdot 1_{E_1^c}+ f \cdot 1_{E_2^c \setminus E_1^c}+ \cdots + f \cdot 1_{E_n^c \setminus (E_1^c \cup \cdots \cup E_{n-1}^c)}$. We see that $f_n$
is measurable and $f_n(x) \to f(x)1_{E^c}(x)$. Hence $f \cdot 1_{E^c}$ is measurable.

Since $m$ is complete, we see that $f \cdot 1_E$ is measurable and hence
$f=f \cdot 1_{E^c}+ f \cdot 1_E$ is measurable.